# Bonjour from Apple

Tags: itunes, windows, bonjour

Is it typical practice to download Bonjour on an HP laptop? I have an HP laptop and Bonjour was downloaded in the last day and I did not download it.

Is Bonjour only for Apple computers?

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour is installed on Windows alongside iTunes or iCloud Control Panel. If you have either of these it is expected to be found to be installed. Bonjour can also be required by other programs or installed separately, so it's existence is not too unusual.